# WooCommerce - Want to show multiple currency for a single product

Tags: functions, plugins, e-commerce

Am using woocommerce - and want to show multiple currency for a single product. I know there is a currency converter widget extension. But am not able to buy it for now.

So if can some one assist me to write a function where I can show multiple currency for a single product - But will pay the base currency which is set in woocommerce settings.

Its just to show how much it costs if you are in different country.

Something like this - http://haet.at/wp-e-commerce-currency-helper/

Please assist.

Regards,
Raghav,

Comment: How far you are already with your function?

Comment: @Max, Nothing so far. If someone could hint on how to proceed. Shall proceed. Can you assist?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at least a pair of plugins have been developed for this:
http://dev.pathtoenlightenment.net/shop/currency-switcher-woocommerce/
and

11/27/15 Deadlink: `http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-currency-converter/4545063`

I couldn't vouch for either as I haven't used either.  I think that some multisite extensions are also in development, which might allow different sub-sites to show the same product in different currencies/prices.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post as one of the top referers in my google analytics...

I'm the author of the plugin mentioned above.

I started working on a shop independent version of the plugin but couldn't complete it yet due to a lack of time.
Obviously I'm a WP E-Commerce coder, but if there is a WooCommerce expert with plugin coding experience out there I'd like to release the plugin together.
Please [contact me](http://haet.at/contact/).

Comment: Does this fit the realm of an answer? I am not so sure. The poster can't comment (yet) though, so I see why he'd end up posting as an answer...

Comment: And, @Hannes: This might interest you - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/woocommerce/topusers - as you can tell from only 1 in 5 questions being answered, our users' combined knowledgebase on Woo products is comparatively limited (as is the case with most commercial themes/plugins/frameworks).

Comment: @JohannesPille I think the low answer rate is also attributable to (generalizing) low quality questions being asked in the WooCommerce tag. I'm pretty fluent in WooCommerce and would answer more questions, but most of the questions are poorly researched and seem to fall under the umbrella of "please work for me for free".

Comment: I have to agree with @helgatheviking. I'm the author of one of the two plugins she mentioned, and I know how complex is handling multiple currencies in WooCommerce. The OP stated that he cannot buy the currency selector plugin made by WooThemes, which is very cheap and would do most of what he asks, therefore the question makes it look like he is looking for free consultancy (otherwise I cannot imagine how can the development cost less than the existing plugin).